# How to get ALL available font styles using ImageSharp?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, fonts, imagesharp

I would like to be able to access all the styles of a font using ImageSharp.

Let's say for example I want to use the font "Bahnschrift" which comes preinstalled with Windows, with the specific style "SemiCondensed". Right now getting the family I am not able to see all the available styles as doing :

```
family.GetAvailableStyles()
```

will just return a collection of enumerators with the fonts in the defined styles. As a consequence I am not able to load that specific style.

I checked [The documentation](https://docs.sixlabors.com/api/Fonts/SixLabors.Fonts.FontFamily.html), but have not been successful in finding any way to specify a custom named font style.

I am welcome to any suggestion, thanks!

Comment: cannot you just load the fonts from files ? 
Just include some .ttf or .otf files in your project and you can access them however you want.

alternatively if you work on windows enviroment you can use System.Drawing

Comment: @jakubpodhaisky thats one way to do it, altought I was hoping for a cleaner solution...

Comment: @SulfurCunk I do not have that much experience with ImageSharp so i hope someone will give you a cleaner solution

Comment: @SulfurChunk Is this an issue you have with any font or just specifically with Bahnschrift?

Comment: @PeterConstable any font that has a style other than Italic, Bold, or ItalicBold

Comment: @SulfurChunk I'm not familiar with imagesharp so can't comment on that. In digital typography, there is a concept of a font _family_, where a family can have one or more specific styles or "faces". Arial and Bahnschrift are examples of famillies; italic, bold and condensed are examples of sub-family styles. Unfortunately, some apps assumed that a family can have only regular, italic, bold and bold italic styles. That meant that anything else needed to be treated as if it were a family distinction. E.g., "Arial Narrow" as a family, contra the typographic understanding of family. (to be cont'd)

Comment: In 2016, OpenType was extended to support continuous style variations. A font using these extensions are referred to as "variable font" (VF). Bahnschrift happens to be a VF (which is why I asked if the issue was specific to it). A font with variation on a weight axis could have light, regular, bold and black weight variants, plus a continuous variety in between. In a VF, the designer could select points in its design variation space and give these specific style names. Bahnschrift has 15 "named instances", such as "SemiBold" and "Light SemiCondensed". (to be cont'd)

Comment: Obviously, in apps that assume a family can have only R, I, B, BI styles, anything else needs to be treated as though it were a separate family. For instance, in Word, "Bahnschrift SemiCondensed" appears in the font family dropdown.<br><br>This might be what's going on in ImageSharp. To use Bahnshcrift SemiCondensed, you might need to look for it as a family rather than as a style of the Bahnschrift family.

Comment: @PeterConstable thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I could not get ImageSharp to reliably find the font famlies in the system fonts, sometimes it would sometimes it wouldn't for seemingly no reason, so in the end I threw together a dirty workaround where I just get the font file and work with that. I don't like it, it's not clean, but unfortunately it's what I have to work with. Thanks for your info though, really helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wondering, as of today the 29th of February 2024, the library does NOT support variable fonts as addressed in [this discussion post](https://github.com/SixLabors/Fonts/discussions/389) on their official Github repository.